# imgur with php - How upload image in my album (error 401 "Authentication required")?

Tags: php, imgur

For uploading image in albums on `imgur.com` it code:

```
if(isset($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'])) {
        $imgbinary = fread(fopen($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], "r"), filesize($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']));
        $image = 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($imgbinary);
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://imgur-apiv3.p.mashape.com/3/image');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'X-Mashape-Key: '. $xmash)); //. $xmash 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Content-Type:  application/x-www-form-urlencoded' ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array( 'image' => $image ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array( 'album' => $album_id ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array( 'type' => 'base64' ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array( 'name' => 'test_name' ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array( 'title' => 'test title' ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array( 'description' => 'blablabla' ));

$reply = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($reply);
curl_close($ch);
```

But now we are get error in answer:

> string(112) "{"data":{"error":"Authentication
>   required","request":"/3/image","method":"POST"},"success":false,"status":401}"

In result we have some questions:

1. How i can auth (on php) ?
2. in docs `https://market.mashape.com/imgur/imgur-9` need paste `Authorization HEADER AUTH`. How get him?

Comment: you have to pass the application key also. i think this is your missing step..

Comment: @cramopy problem with `X-Mashape-Key` was solved, but now we get error `Authentication required`...

Answer (score 0):

> need to join these into one array and thus one set call:

```
$headers = array('Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id, 'X-Mashape-Key: ' . $Mashape_Key)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```